# Saving data coming from the view to a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<% for product in @order.line_items -%>
<% total_price += (product.price * product.quantity) -%>
<tr>
    <td><strong><%= product.item.description%></strong></td>
    <td><%= product.item.category.category_name%></td>
    <td><%= product.quantity%></td>
    <td><%= product.price%></td>

</tr>
<% end -%>
```

How do i save total_price to my database? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a method to your `Order` model that computes the total price for an order:

```
def total_price
  line_items.sum('price * quantity')
end
```

With this you can do:

```
@order.total_price
```

An added advantage of this method is that the computation is done in the database. No need iterating over all the line items.

Answer (score 2):

In your example you are working in the view. The view is not made to manipulate the Data its there to display data. When you want to add a method that provides you the total price you can add it to your model:

```
def total_price
     self.price*self.quantity
end
```

Then you can call it like this in your view:

```
<%= product.total_price %>
```

A principle is that you never store data in the database that could be calculated from other fields that are already in the database.

Also you shouldnt use the `for` loop. Use iteration like This:

```
<% @order.line_items.each do |product| %>
      <%= stuff you do......  %>
<% end %>
```

When you want the sum you can do:

```
@order.line_items.collect(&:total_price).sum
```

Comment: Thanks! but how can i retain the += function?

Comment: `for item in collection` is just another way of writing `collection.each do |item|`. Why *shouldn't* he use that??

Comment: @Mischa: Its not "rubish" to use the `for item in collection` thats like writing `object.method(attr1, attr2)` instead of `object.method attr1, attr2`

Comment: There is [a reason not to use `for`](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/the_evils_of_the_for_loop).